# Infiny calculator

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to make an infinity calculator (with numbers upper and lower than an int size), only working with strings.
I'm doing addition but i meet problems when i need to report tens to the next character : like 9 + 7 = 16 i will put 6 in the current character and 1 to the next char of my result string.
Here is my code :

```
 char    *add_inf(char *nb1, char *nb2, char *rslt)
{
  if (*nb1 && *nb2)
    {
      *rslt = (*nb1 - '0' + *nb2 - '0' > 9 ? (*nb1 - '0' + *nb2 - '0') % 10 : *nb1 - '0' + *nb2 - '0') + *rslt - '0' + '0';
      if (*nb1 - '0' + *nb2 - '0' > 9)
        {
          rslt++;
          *rslt = '1'; //Here i put the next char to '1'
          add_inf(nb1 + 1, nb2 + 1, rslt);
        }
      add_inf(nb1 + 1, nb2 + 1, rslt + 1);
    }
  return (rslt);
}
```

Sorry for the mess with - '0' and + '0', i should make a fonction to sub it and add it before doing calculations.
When the input is nb1 = "11111111" and nb2 = "58856557" the output is correct :

```
69967668
```

But when i input nb1 = "11111114" and nb2 = "588856557" the output is :

```
699676611
```

In the place of adding 1 to the next char and having :

```
69967671
```

It just add the '1' char to my result string.
Ideas?

Comment: One question: how would you make your function add `4` and `99999` (or even `99990`)?

Comment: I have reduce my code to the minimum for more comprehension. I'm managing the addition of two different length string, if that is your question

Comment: Well then, just add a dummy `0` to the string before. So instead of adding `"4"` and `"99999"` you end up adding `"04"` and `"099999"`. This solves your problem with the extra leading `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. I'm going to show you three equivalent lines of code:

```
*rslt = (*nb1 - '0' + *nb2 - '0' > 9 ? (*nb1 - '0' + *nb2 - '0') % 10 : *nb1 - '0' + *nb2 - '0') + *rslt - '0' + '0';
```

When `*nb1 - '0' + *nb2 - '0' <= 9`, both the true and the false sides of the conditional will have the **same output**. Because of that, we can take this **awful** line of code (which took actual time to parse), and rewrite it as a much clearer:

```
*rslt = ((*nb1 - '0' + *nb2 - '0') % 10) + *rslt - '0' + '0';
```

We can also use the += operator to clean it up a touch more.

```
*rslt += (*nb1 - '0' + *nb2 - '0') % 10;
```

#### 2. Your user input

It's not clear how you call this function. I assume `rslt` is a string of `'0'` that is at least one byte **longer** than the other two strings.

#### 3. Overflow

You don't properly check for overflow. Let's look at a simple case: `"54" + "65"`. On the first loop, you will properly store `1` as the result in the first place. And you will carry a `1` to the next iteration.

On the next iteration however, you don't use the carry bit to test if you overflowed. Here, your code will say that `lhs + rhs == 9`, so you're good. But in reality, it's `lhs + rhs + carry == 10`!

#### 4. Everything Klas Lindbäck said.

[In this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26406536/47453)

#### 5. Return value

Presumably, you always want the return value to point to the full `rslt` string. Your code won't do that. When you overflow, you increment the value of `rslt`. So if the first 2 characters cause an overflow, your return value will actually be a pointer to the second character of the full `rslt` string.

#### 6. Therefore...

So if we take all of this to heart, we could produce some code that looks like this.

```
char *add_inf(char *nb1, char *nb2, char *rslt) {
    if (*nb1 && *nb2) {
        int sum = (*nb1 - '0' + *nb2 - '0' + *rslt - '0');

        *(rslt + 0) = (sum % 10) + '0';
        if (sum / 10)
            *(rslt + 1) = (sum / 10) + '0';

        add_inf(nb1 + 1, nb2 + 1, rslt + 1);
    }

    return rslt;
}

int main() {
    char nb1[]    = "11111114";
    char nb2[]    = "58856557";
    char output[] = "000000000";

    add_inf(nb1, nb2, output);
    printf("%s\n", output);
}
```

Which gets the same **broken** answer that you got as well! What's going on here?

Well, your code is assuming that the least significant bit is the one on the left, and the most significant bit is on the right. So in your string, if you wanted to add the numbers 100 and 200, you would actually do `inf_add("001", "002");`

If that's not what you want, then you need to iterate the strings in the **reverse order**!

#### 7. What would code for the reverse order look like?

Well, it's a touch annoying to do it recursively, so I'm just going to use a loop.

```
char *add_inf(char *nb1, char *nb2, char *rslt) {
    int len = strlen(nb1);
    int carry = 0;

    for (int i=len - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        int sum = (nb1[i] - '0' + nb2[i] - '0' + carry);

        rslt[i] = (sum % 10) + '0';
        carry   = (sum / 10);
    }

    return rslt;
}

int main() {
    char nb1[]    = "11111114";
    char nb2[]    = "58856557";
    char output[] = "00000000";

    add_inf(nb1, nb2, output);
    printf("%s\n", output);
}
```

This produces, as you probably wanted:

```
69967671
```

Note that in this code, we iterate the strings from the end of the string, to the beginning of the string.

Additionally, right before the `return`, we could test `carry` to see if it is non-zero. If it is non-zero, we could assert or whatever to notify the user of an overflow on the addition.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing an "else":

```
 char    *add_inf(char *nb1, char *nb2, char *rslt)
{
  if (*nb1 && *nb2)
    {
      *rslt = (*nb1 - '0' + *nb2 - '0' > 9 ? (*nb1 - '0' + *nb2 - '0') % 10 : *nb1 - '0' + *nb2 - '0') + *rslt - '0' + '0';
      if (*nb1 - '0' + *nb2 - '0' > 9)
        {
          rslt++;
          *rslt = '1'; //Here i put the next char to '1'
          add_inf(nb1 + 1, nb2 + 1, rslt);
        }
      else  // sum is less than 10
          add_inf(nb1 + 1, nb2 + 1, rslt + 1);
    }
  return (rslt);
}
```

I don't understand the order - the code should only work if the strings are stored in reverse order when you do the addition.

Comment: Hum you are maybe right for the order, need to try it ! But i thing i have no need of the else as i call back add_inf if *nb1 + *nb2 > 9

Comment: Would also be nice to avoid "array index out of bounds" (e.g. maybe by checking and resizing the array).

Comment: @Robin Since there is no `return` after the first `add_inf`, the code will call `add_inf` a second time once it returns from the recursion. The else is necessary to prevent that.